# passing parameter in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing data between asp.net pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639965/passing-data-between-asp-net-pages)

how to pass value of TEXTBOX from one page to another page in ASP.NET c# I need, not by using URL string query method. I do need passing from one page to another without passing values by URL.

Comment: kappa's comment is a duplicate of onof's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the session state.

```
Session["TextBoxValue"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

Then, retrieve it on the other page:

```
string val = Session["TextBoxValue"];
```

Comment: Also I am getting an error while compiling .csproj file to obtain dll file. The error is cs0103 error TextBox01 not found in the current context. though I created a TextBox correctly...

Comment: Please start another thread for your questions above.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a form in the first page, this form contains your required parameters and use an action redirect to another page like in this example:

```
<form method="post" action="yoursecondpage.aspx">
  <input ... />
</form>
```

Another way is using a `Server.Transfer("mySecondPage", true)`, in the second page, on Page_Load event you can cast "PreviousPage as MySecondPage" and get properties .