# How to pass objects, not values, between pages in ASP.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

At the moment I pass values from one page to another. I need to pass objects between pages, how can I do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see: [Passing data between asp.net pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2639965/102112)

Comment: When you say - you pass values from one page to another, I assume you are referring to QueryString.... You may want to use Session to pass data from one page to another. However - there are other alternatives(Cache Object/ Application Object) to manage data between pages based on the requirements.

Comment: if i want to do it using session, could you provide us with some code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

save object in Session or Cache and then redirect to other page?
lets say you have a.aspx in a.aspx you add item to Session.

```
Session["Item"] = myObjectInstance;
```

in b.aspx you will get object;

```
var myObjectInstance = (MyObjectInstance) Session["Item"];
```

but you should check if anyvalue is set in Session before using it.

Answer (score 5):

you could serialize the object into an `input` field in HTML and submit it via `form`. Then deserialize it back to the object on the page the form submits to with `Request['paramName']`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Serialize an object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Serialize<T>(T data)
{
    string functionReturnValue = string.Empty;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, data);

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        functionReturnValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return functionReturnValue;
}

/// <summary>
/// Deserialize object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xml"></param>
/// <returns>Object<T></returns>
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        T theObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        return theObject;
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to HTML encode the data, when you pass it via URL.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize an object in ASP very easily, here are 3 approaches suited for different types of requirements:

1- Using Session to pass objects on Asp:

```
//In A.aspx
//Serialize.
Object obj = MyObject;
Session["Passing Object"] = obj;

//In B.aspx
//DeSerialize.
MyObject obj1 = (MyObject)Session["Passing Object"];

Returntype of the method xyx = obj.Method;//Using the deserialized data.
```

2- To save on your Asp project solution itself:

```
//Create a folder in your asp project solution with name "MyFile.bin"
//In A.aspx
//Serialize.
IFormatter formatterSerialize = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream streamSerialize = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFile.bin/MyFiles.xml"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatterSerialize.Serialize(streamSerialize, MyObject);
streamSerialize.Close();

//In B.aspx
//DeSerialize.
IFormatter formatterDeSerialize = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream streamDeSerialize = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFile.bin/MyFiles.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
MyObject obj = (MyObject)formatterDeSerialize.Deserialize(streamDeSerialize);
streamDeSerialize.Close();

Returntype of the method xyx = obj.Method;//Using the deserialized data.
```

3- To save on client machine................

```
String fileName = @"C:\MyFiles.xml";//you can keep any extension like .xyz or .yourname, anything, not an issue.
//In A.aspx
//Serialize.
IFormatter formatterSerialize = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream streamSerialize = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatterSerialize.Serialize(streamSerialize, MyObject);
streamSerialize.Close();

//In B.aspx
//DeSerialize.
IFormatter formatterDeSerialize = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream1 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
MyObject obj = (MyObject)formatterDeSerialize.Deserialize(stream1);
stream1.Close();

Returntype of the method xyx = obj.Method;//Using the deserialized data.
```

Answer (score 1):

Serializing multiple objects into list elements in as xml file and deserializing them

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("ClassList")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ClassElements))] //Adds class containing elentsof list
public class ClassList
{
    private String FFolderName;
    private List<ClassElements> ListOfElements;

    [XmlArray("ClassListArray")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ClassElementObjects")]
    public List<ClassElements> ListOfElements = new List<ClassElements>();

    [XmlElement("Listname")]
    public string Listname { get; set; }

    public void InitilizeClassVars() 
    {

    }

    public ClassList() 
    {
        InitilizeClassVars();
    }

    public void AddClassElementObjects aItem)
    {
        ListOfElements.Add(aItem);
    }
}

[XmlType("ClassElements")]
public class ClassElements
{
    private String str1;
    private int iInt;
    private Double dblDouble;

    [XmlAttribute("str", DataType = "string")]
    public String str
    {
        get { return str; }
    }

    [XmlElement("iInt")]
    public int iInt
    {
        get { return iInt;}
        set { iInt = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("dblDouble")]
    public Double dblDouble
    {
        get { return dblDouble; }
        set { dblDouble = value; }
    }

    public void InitilizeClassVars()
    {

    }

    public ClassElements()
    {
        InitilizeClassVars();
    }
}
```

**In Button Click or Serializing point..**

```
ClassList ListOfObjs = new ClassList();
int Count = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    ClassElements NewObj = new ClassElements();
    NewObj.str = "Hi";
    NewObj.iInt = 500;
    NewObj.dblDouble = 5000;
    ListOfObjs.Add(NewObj);
}

// Serialize 
String fileName = @"C:\MyFiles.xml";

Type[] elements = { typeof(ClassElements) };
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassList), elements);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
serializer.Serialize(fs, ListOfObjs);
fs.Close();
ListOfObjs = null;
```

**In Button Click or DeSerializing point..**

```
ClassList ListOfObjs = new ClassList();

String fileName = @"C:\MyFiles.xml";

// Deserialize 
fs = new FileStream(fileName , FileMode.Open);
personen = (ListOfObjs)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, ListOfObjs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to put these values into the Session. However, a rule of thumb for session variables is that they should be kept to a minimum.

What we do is keep the state in a 'stateserver'. This is merely a table in the database that stores values by user.

This table has an xml column which contains the objects from our state which are [xmlserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx). The downside is that you are dependent on the xmlserializer and it's [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109318/using-net-what-limitations-if-any-are-there-in-using-the-xmlserializer). Plus performance wise... on each request you need to perform a query, deserialize the state, process the request, serialize the state again and update the changes back to the database. This is not very optimal when you have a high traffic website.

If hardware is not a problem, a better alternative is to use a [real stateserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx) and just use the session.